# Eigenvalue of a sum of power matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

Let $A\in \mathbb {R}^{n\times n}$, and $\|A\|=\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is the largest eigenvalue of $A$, and $0<\lambda<1$. Let $\vec b$ be the eigenvector of $A$ which corresponds to $\lambda$.

It's true that $\vec b$ is also an eigenvector which corresponds to $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}A^{i}$.

I know that $\left\|\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}A^{i}\vec b\right\|=\left\|\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lambda^{i}\vec b\right\|=\left\|\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lambda^{i}\right\|\|\vec b\|$. I want to know whether I can have $\left\|\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lambda^{i}\right\|\|\vec b\|=\left\|\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}A^{i}\right\|\|\vec b\|$, which is to say $\left\|\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lambda^{i}\right\|$ is the largest eigenvalue of $\left\|\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}A^{i}\right\|$. Intuitively, I think it is true and might be some theorem.

Comment: I know that if $\|A\|=\lambda$, then $\|A^{2}\|=\lambda^{2}$. But I don't know if this is true for power summation.

Comment: I know that $\|\vec v+\vec u\|=\|\vec v\|+\|\vec u\|$ if and only $\vec v$ and $\vec u$ are linearly dependent. I don't know if there's a similar property for matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}A^{i}$ is nothing but $A(I-A)^{-1}$ and its eigen values are of the form $\frac c {1+c}$ where $c$ is an eigen value of $A$. From this it follows that that the largest eigen value of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}A^{i}$ is $\frac {\lambda} {1+\lambda}$ which is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\lambda^{i}$.